# Question about UIWindow backgrounds

Tags: iphone, ios, background, uiwindow, firmware

I have written a powerful trig calculator, but I want to use the "linen" background. I have been able to implement this in interface builder, but I get a 'yellow triangle' warning in Xcode that says it is not compatible with something like iOS 3.2 and earlier. And I'm afraid Apple will reject it if says that. I want to know the code that I can use to change both the text color (from black to white) and the background texture (from blue and white vertical stripes to the darker linen). I already know a few ways to test and apply info about the users current firmware version, but I'm always open to suggestions. Any help will be GREATLY APPRECIATED!!! I have just read the first 3 answers and duh I feel kinda stupid, that makes sense. But I would also like to know how to do this and make it like a user configurable "setting" just to make it feel nicer :-) thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linen background is a tiling UIColor. You can create a tile color programmatically and apply this tiled background anywhere you would set a backgroundColor. Even on UIWindow.

Comment: [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain compatibility to old iOS versions, replace the built in background "color" (such as `linen`) with an UIImageView showing an image of it.

Write a simple app, filling the entire screen with the background, make a screenshot, then place it behind all other UI elements.